# Squares in an alien language

Tags: encoded-message

*Inspired by Lopsy's [excellent puzzle idea](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/4932/linguistics-japanese-squares), I thought I'd try my hand at coming up with a puzzle that's not simply a real-world language.*

Once again, we have the squares 1, 4, 9, ... , 81, 100 in some order — but this time it's in an alien language! Once you figure out which is which, can you tell me how you think you would say 42 and 58?

```
an
ansont
ansont carton-catr
ansont derton el an
cartva
catr
catrsont
detrsont derton-catr
yorton el an
yotrsont anva
```

Comment: the numbers listed are all between (including) 1 and 100, but the ones you said "1,4,9..." aren't necessarily the ones listed, right?

Comment: @Raystafarian: those are the first _squares_. Since the list is a list of the squares form 1-100, I think that 1,4,9 _are_ indeed in the list. At least I hope so :P

Comment: @Raystafarian As oerkelens says, this a list of the first ten square numbers, from one to a hundred.

Comment: *square numbers* - okay. I didn't gather the "numbers" part of that.

Comment: Sounds like French.

Comment: +1 I liked doing this one :) Even when I suspected where the trick lay, it still took some time to figure it out :)

Comment: Very neat puzzle!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I would say 42 as *ansont yorton-detr* and 58 as *detrsont yortva*.

I will write up my line of thinking, but I really hope I'm on the right track :)

> I suspected that these aliens would not use base 10. I tried with 16 and 8, which looked promising, but I didn't get far.
>
>  Looking at the given words, there seem to be some "multipliers": *sont* and *ton* and *va*; as basic numerals, it seems we have four candidates: *an*, *catr*, *detr* and *yotr*.
>  *El* I assume to be *and* or *minus*. It seems that in combination with the *-ton* and the *-va* ending, *tr* becomes *rt*, probably because it is easier to pronounce. Combined with *-sont*, *tr* stays *tr*.
>
>  Since we have four single digit words, and *zero* is unlikely to be used, I tried base-5 (0,1,2,3,4).
>  If we write the first ten squares as base-5, we get:
>  1, 4, 14, 31, 100, 121, 144, 224, 311, 400.
>
>  Assuming *sont* to mean 100, and having three ansonts, it seems *an* = 1. That solves *an* and *ansont* (1 and 100 base-5). 
>  If *el an* is *and 1*, derton el an is "xx and 1", probably 21. That solves *ansont derton el an* (121 base-5).
>
>  *ansont carton-catr* must then be 144 base 5. That means *catr* is 4, and *catrsont* is 400 base 5. 
>  We have one (multiple of 5) + 1, so 31 must be *yorton el an*, and *yotr* means 3. *Detr* meaning 2 means *detrsont  derton-catr* is 224.
>
>  That leaves *cartva* and *yotrsont anva* for 14 and 311: *va* following the word means the number is preceded by a 1: *cartva* is 4 preceded by 1, *anva* is 1 preceded by one.

Now for the actual answer:

> We have a base-5 system and the following vocabulary:
>  an = 1
>  detr = 2
>  yotr = 3
>  catr = 4
>  [foo]va = 1[foo]
>  el an = and 1
>  -ton = 10
>  -sont = 100
>
>  let's see if we can speak this language:
>
>  42 is once 25 (100) + three times 5 (30) + 2. So *ansont yorton detr*.
>  58 is twice 25 (200) + one 5 (10) + 3. So *detrsont yortva*.

Comment: Rather than "on the right track", you're completely spot on, even concerning `tr` becoming `rt` solely for pronunciation! As A.E. mentions in the comments the language was based on French — this was to ensure that the puzzle was solvable but had enough quirks to feel natural :)