# Squares in another alien language

Tags: cipher

Inspired by [this puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/4964/squares-in-an-alien-language).

In a newly discovered alien language, the following phrases are the pronunciations for the square numbers up to 100 (1, 4, 9, 16 .. 100). Match each phrase with the appropriate number.

```
be
be gurruvan
be ruvan kar
kar
ru gursivan
ru rukar
ru sivan
si
si gurdavan
si sivan kar
```

Bonus: How do you pronounce 31 and 58 in this system?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Firstly, the assignment of squares to phrases:

> The aliens appear to count in base 7, so the first ten squares are:
>  1, 4, 12, 22, 34, 51, 100, 121, 144 and 202
>
>  And they are pronounced thus:
>
> ```
>  4    be
>  34   be gurruvan
>  144  be ruvan kar
>  100  kar
>  12   ru gursivan
>  202  ru rukar
>  22   ru sivan
>  1    si
>  51   si gurdavan
>  121  si sivan kar
> ```

Some explanation:

> The phrases are little-endian (start with the units and work up).
>  The units words for 1, 2, 3 and 4 are si, ru, da and be respectively.
>
>  The tens words are all suffixed "-van", but they also appear with and without a "gur-" prefix, so the numbers don't align as you would first expect (E.g. ru=2 but gurruvan=30 and ruvan=40). (This was probably the biggest stumbling block to solving for me.)
>  Alternatively, the "-van" suffix is a twenties multiplier, with the "gur-" prefix indicating ten less. So (*xx*-van = 20*xx, and gur-*xx*-van = 20*x-10)
>
>  And finally 100 is kar.
>
>  From that, we can build the following translation table (italics for entries that don't appear in the first ten squares):
>
> ```
>     Units  "Tens"    "Hundreds"
>  0  ?      ?         ?
>  1  si     gursivan  kar
>  2  ru     sivan     rukar
>  3  da     gurruvan  dakar
>  4  be     ruvan     bekar
>  5  ?      gurdavan  ?
>  6  ?      davan     ?
> ```

And for the bonus:

> 31(decimal) = 43 (base 7) = da ruvan
>  58(decimal) = 112 (base 7) = ru gursivan kar

Comment: I think you don't have the decimals complete yet. I think van actually means 20 (in base 7) and gur means -10 (in base 7). So ruvan is 2*20=40, sivan is 1*20=20, gurruvan is -10 + 2*20=30, gursivan is -10 + 2*20 and finally gurdavan is -10 + 3*20.

Comment: @quarague I was slightly ahead of you. See latest edit.

Comment: Yep, that's it, well done. For reference, this system is inspired by Danish counting, where 58 is pronounced as 8 + ((3-0.5)*20)