# Japanese puzzle 1

Tags: word, language, video-games

Here are 3 Japanese symbols.

竜 : Dragon

昇 : Rise up

拳 : Fist

Can you find the video game related word I am looking for by using only these 3 symbols as clues?

Comment: I will try a new line of puzzles by trying to incorporate my Japanese knowledge into them and see how it goes. Let me know what you think!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The word is probably:

> 昇竜拳 = Shoryuken, or Rising-Dragon Fist from the Street Fighter franchise.

I don't really have any explanation related to the characters, though, I just googled the English meanings you provided. Not sure what the puzzle here is.

Comment: Wow... Google just killed my puzzle... It was meant to be easy for a starter but.... it seems that just posting the 3 definitions in any orders in good makes it come up top of the search list. I was hoping for something more in the line of playing around in a japanese to english dictionary to find the correct order of the symbols etc. I guess as it stands it's not even worth being a puzzle?

Comment: For translation-type puzzles, there was one I rather liked: the Chinese characters for 1 to 10, then each multiple of 10 up to 100 were listed, and users were challenged to deduce which character represented which digit. You could do the same with many move-names and explain context, allowing people to assign meaning to each character?

Comment: @stackreader: finally found it! http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/4932/linguistics-japanese-squares

Answer (score 1):

My guess is

> [Dragon Scroll](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dragon_Scroll)

Reason

> The cover of this Konami game shows a dragon risen with its wings up. Not sure if this is how it needs to be solved.

Picture

> [image]